# Creating matrix by multiply columns

Tags: python

I want to create matrix as it is shown at the picture:
Creating new matrices by multiplying columns of matrix in elementwise

Is it possible to create it without using 3 for loop?

[image: Figure]

Comment: Have you tried `numpy.multiply` and 2 loops?

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit hard to verify without actual input and desired output data, but you can use NumPy reshaping and [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to do the operation without any for loops:

```
a = numpy.arange(3 * 6).reshape(3, 6)
b = numpy.arange(3 * 3).reshape(3, 3)
c = numpy.arange(3 * 2).reshape(3, 2)

x = a.reshape(3, 3, 2).transpose(1, 0, 2) * b[..., None]
y = a.reshape(3, 3, 2).transpose(0, 2, 1) * c[..., None]
```